# How to install Git Extension on MacOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, git

I need to install GitExtension on MacOS, but I can't find any info about this.

I found this link

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/

after download I get compressed folder there is inside `.exe` file. I can't execute `.exe` file on macOS...

So, maybe someone uses Git Extension on his laptop, please share an experience or maybe an alternative way should be used?

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/wiki/How-To:-run-Git-Extensions-on-Linux also, which app are you using this extension for  ? VSCode ? visual studio ? https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions

Comment: @ankii I don't get what do you mean from your first link? It is a Linux description... I would like to use git extension independently, I mean not like a part of IDE (like VisualStudio)...

Comment: @Sirop4ik Were you able to run Gitextentions on mac?

Comment: @Knu8 no, finally I ended up with SourceTree, in spite of that Git Extension I liked it much more...

Comment: That's unfortunate. I really miss it. I personally end up using gitmap in VS code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some other Git visual front-ends for macOS you might consider:

- [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (free)
- [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) (free)
- [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) (free evaluation, $49.99 after that)
- [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) (Free Personal)

Comment: Yes, I thought about it... I just get used to GitExtension... Also, I know GitKraken, but with the last update, they restricted work with private repositories...

Comment: None of those offer side-by-side diff.

Comment: upvoted! @Agent_L source tree is good. not exactly side by side diff, but unified view is there. Also you can use it's menu item "external diff.." to launch the FileMerge tool which can show a side by side diff.

Comment: @ankii SC is crap. It can't push what I'm telling it to push so I have to push manually into gerrit. It can't remember how much history I wanted and every click it reverts to "All Branches". SC feels like student project abandoned after first working feature, it's good for editing commit message and that's pretty much it. BTW, if I wanted to launch external tool, why would I need a frontend?  Launching external tool is commandline philosophy, the whole point of integrated client is to not have to do it. The MacOS problem is that half-baked programs pass "because you can do rest in cmd".

Answer (score 2):

The footnote of the [How to Run](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/wiki/How-To:-run-Git-Extensions-on-Linux) addresses Mac :

> macOS Mono support for Git Extensions is unknown.
>
> Note specifically though that you at least in 5.4 must run tMono in 32bit version as the 64bit WinForm support is incomplete. Start with --arch=32. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/

Also, the wikis contain only [2 results for mac](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/search?q=mac&unscoped_q=mac&type=Wikis):

- > Version 2.5x (release/2.5x branch): 
  >   JetBrains Rider/MonoDevelop (Linux) / MS Visual Studio for Mac (Mac)

  So it is/was supported with  MS Visual Studio.
- > Version 2.5x was the last cross-platform version, running both on Windows (MS .NET Framework) and on Linux/Mac (Mono).
  >
  > This branch is in maintenance mode with no significant active development planned. ...